# Is it possible to pass form data as a request body in options of http request in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

For [my](https://github.com/nunisa/nodejsprojects) app, I've written a simple **service client** module to send http requests to my api end-points for CRUD operations in which I'm, currently, sending the **form data** as a **query string** with api end-points (which I think is not the right method). In api, in order to make it **POSTman** compatible, I'm always checking if request body is **undefined** else I'm getting the form data from the query string. So far so good and everything is working fine but what I need is, **I want to pass the form data as a request body in options of http request**.  
I've gone through [node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) for http request and many other related articles regarding the same but did not find the exact solution for my requirement. So, Please help me out here.  
Following are some chunks of source codes from my app:-

1. **routes/defaultController.js**

   ```
   // Default controller
   var Services = require('./service-client');

   function add_place(req, res){
   var thisRes = res;
   var apiClient = new Services(req, '/api/places');
   if(req.method != 'GET'){
       apiClient.post(req.body, function(err, res){
           console.log(res);
           thisRes.redirect('/');
       });
   }else{
       res.render('add-place', {
           title: 'Add Express'
       });
   }
   }
   ```
2. **routes/service-client.js**

   ```
   var http = require('http');
   var querystring = require('querystring');

   Services.prototype.post = function(form_data, callback){
   var post_data = querystring.stringify(form_data);
   this.description.path = this.apiURL+'?'+post_data;
   this.description.method = 'POST';
   var options = this.description;
   var temp = http.request(options, function(res){
       res.setEncoding('utf8');
       res.on('data', function (chunk) {
           callback(null, chunk);
       });
   });
   temp.end();
   };
   ```
3. **routes/api-place.js**

   ```
   var Place = require('../models/place');
   require('../db-config')(app);

   router.post('/', function(req, res){
   var name = (req.body.name != undefined)?req.body.name:req.query.name;
   var city = (req.body.city != undefined)?req.body.city:req.query.city;
   var state = (req.body.state != undefined)?req.body.state:req.query.state;
   var place = new Place({
       name: name,
       city: city,
       state: state
   });
   place.save(function(err){
       if (err) throw err;
       res.json({message: 'Created'});
   });
   });
   ```
4. **app.js**

   ```
   var apiPlaces = require('./routes/api-places');
   app.use('/api/places', apiPlaces);

   // wire request controllers
   var defaultController = require('./routes/defaultController');
   defaultController.wire(app);
   ```

   Thanks!